# 英語による質問は英語版の方へ移行できますか？

Tags: 討議, 機能の要求

時折、スタック・オーバーフローにおいて「英語による質問」が見受けられます。

せっかく質問して頂いても、回答がどのような言語が良いのかなど回答者も戸惑ってしまったり、(第三者が)翻訳した際に意図した表現が崩れてしまうことや、質問者が英語のみしか理解できなかった場合、回答を理解いただけず問題を解決することができないかと思います。

このようなケースでは質問を移行したほうが良いのかと思いますが、そういったことは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 8, accepted):

はい、できます。

もし英語の投稿を見た場合、通報してください。通報のメッセージの中に「英語版に移動してください」等を記載したら、モデレーターが移動できます。

そして、質問内の両方の投稿を移動しました。

Comment: [S2JSFをGlassfishでデプロイするとエラーが発生する](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809314/no-factories-configured-for-this-application)を通報せずに訳した理由はS2JSFが日本製のものだったからです。質問者が「日本版で質問した方が回答が得られやすい」と考えたのかと思いました。まあ、もしそうであればその旨を質問に記載して欲しいところですね。

Comment: @kotatsu 難しいところですね。一方では日本語版で聞くなら日本語にしないと思いながら、日本のコミュニティーを信頼ができたら何かの形でここに期待できればいいと思います。そのバランスの取り方があればいいと思いますね。

Comment: 私も同様に意図的に日本語SOに投稿されたのだと考えました。Seasarプロジェクトに関してはメーリングリストにコミッターが常駐している事情もあって、そちらの方が回答を得るにはより適しているだろうと、コメントでMLに誘導するにとどめています。ちなみにMLではおそらく同僚の日本人が同じ質問をしています。[Seasar-user:22086 GlassFish V3のクラスロードについて](http://ml.seasar.org/archives/seasar-user/2015-August/022089.html)

Comment: この質問を受ける数日前なのですが、日本語が話せる人が意図的に英語で質問をしてきている質問がありました。コメントの会話で日本語を使ってもらったので確かです。英語版に日本語で投稿したことがないのでわかりませんが、向こうではあまりいい印象ではないと思います（スパムになる？）。その質問文は翻訳で綺麗に日本語に直せる英語でした。ですので、移行しようというのはちょっとした意地悪です。そこまで出来るのなら自分のレベルを外で確かめてこい！回答できるレベルあるだろ？と言うような意地悪なのです。　 @jmac さん　プログラムだけの投稿を規制できるのなら英文のみの投稿も規制したほうが英語版での移行による重複がなく移行によるスパムをなくせるかと思います。

Answer (score 2):

質問時からは時間が経っているので、いま現在の対応方法を念のため別回答としておきます。

---

技術的には他サイトへの移行は可能ではありますが、まず質問者本人の意思を確認する必要があります。

- いったん質問をクローズして「日本語版と英語版の違い」をメッセージで伝えます。
- 英語での質問を希望する場合には、英語版への再投稿を基本的に勧めています。
- もし実際に移行をする場合でも、英語版以外により特定の話題に特化した関連サイトがそれぞれあるので、適切なサイトに移行してあげるべきでしょう。
  (Ubuntu向けの [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), Vim向けの [Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/), Blendar向けの [Blendar](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) など)