# 英語で回答しても構いませんか？

Tags: 討議, 回答の仕方

以下の質問に英語での回答が行われている、という通報を受けました。

[VPNの動作確認のために中国からの接続が成功するかどうか確認する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/12225/8000)

これが質問であれば、現状では[英語版サイトに移動](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1933/8000)することが多いです。一方で、[理由があれば受け入れても構わない](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1815/8000)といった意見も過去にはありました。

では、回答の場合はどうでしょうか？懸念点等あればそれも挙げていただければと思います。

<sub>https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1959 でもこの点に触れた回答がありましたが、スコアが低めだったこともあり、独立した質問にしてみました。</sub>

Comment: so に参加していく中で、この問いに対する自分の答えが何回か変わっていて、難しい問題だなと感じています。

Answer (score 17):

英語で回答してもよい。**回答の本質は言語ではなくその内容である**

---

英語の回答を受け付けて良い理由

1. 質問者の理解できる言語であれば日本語でなくとも**質問者本人には有益かもしれない**
2. 本文の言語に関係なく**回答に含まれるコードが有益かもしれない**

懸念点

1. 質問者が回答文やコメントを理解できないかもしれない
2. その言語（この例では英語）を標準的な言語としたサイトであると誤認されるかもしれない

懸念に対してできること

1. それができる者は英語の回答文の日本語訳を編集によって追記する

---

日本語を読めるが日本語の回答文を正確に書く自信がない者が英語を用いると仮定して、質問に対して答えを持っている者を排除することは得策ではない。解決につながる有益な回答であるなら**回答文を翻訳すれば日本語の質問と回答のセットが完成する**

俺は英語で質問文などを書くのは苦手だがプログラミング関連の英語を読むことはできる。日本語で質問ができて英語圏のユーザーにも回答が貰えるなら素晴らしい。ここ**スタック・オーバーフローで重要なのは自身の抱える問題を日本語で皆に伝えられること**であり日本語の回答は望ましいがそれに限定されるべきではない

---

本文の言語ではないが[ios](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios)に関する質問では[objective-c](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c)で期待される回答に[swift](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift)のコード（またはその逆や[c](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)など期待とは異なるプログラミング言語）を出されている例をたびたび見かける。この時、質問者によっては回答を元に自身で期待される言語に翻訳している。本文の言語でこれが起こってもいいだろう

---

実際に翻訳* して感じた点

1. 翻訳文の追記位置を統一したほうがよい
2. 全文翻訳のみか一部翻訳でもよいか
3. コメントを翻訳する場合どこに翻訳文を投稿したらよいか
4. 他言語の本文が改稿され翻訳文は修正されないことが起こりうる
5. 役に立たないと感じた投稿は翻訳しなくてもよいのか

<sub>* 『[OnApplicationQuit is not called...](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/8462/)』の質問文、『[VPNの動作確認のために中国からの...](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12225/)』の回答文を翻訳。『[if ((ret = func()) == -1)という書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1961/)』の回答文の翻訳は「見たことあるよ。よくない書き方だよね」程度の同意で占められた内容のため翻訳しなかった</sub>

Answer (score 13):

### 英語での回答は控えてもらいたいと思います

もちろん受け入れることの利点ははっきりと理解しています。
しかし、受け入れることによって

---

- **編集の負担やレビューの負担が増えます。**

信用度が少ない人が信用度を集めるためには有効的かもしれませんが、その作業によって多くのレビューが発生します。適切に翻訳の結果を確認し承認することができればよいのですが、翻訳の場合だと原文との比較が必要になり負担になります。

---

- **利用者が多い言語で日本語と英語の間の言語について考えなおす必要が出てきます。**

googleで翻訳可能な言語は９０にもなります。Windowsの[言語対応](http://windows.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/language-packs#lptabs=win10)では110を超える言語があります。その言語の中で、日本語は母国語としては９番目に利用者が多く、公用語としては１１番目に利用者の多い言語です。[参考](http://japan.wipgroup.com/useful-information/reference-material-data/gengosiyoujinkou.html) 英語の次に多いには日本語ではないのです。 日本語より利用者の多い言語なら受け入れますか？質問者のために翻訳をする努力を惜しみませんか？

---

- **質問者の意に反した回答の可能性があります。**

質問者が英語を読めるのであれば、英語のページを検索できたはずです。が、なぜ？わざわざ日本語で質問を投稿したのか？考える必要があります。

---

- **すべての日本人に対して有効な回答とは言えません**

英語の教育が行われているとはいえ、すべての人が上手に英語を使えるわけではありません。翻訳機を利用したとしても前後関係等の確認は必要になります。

---

- **投票の機会が失われる**

英語であるために読まれずに投票されない可能性があります。または、マイナスに投票される。

---

- **すべてのコードに可読性があるとは限りません**

本当にすべての人に読みやすく理解しやすいコードが記述されると言う保証はありません。コードとして括られていなかったり説明が混在していたりする可能性や、[アスキーアートコード](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOCCC)ではない保証はありません。

---

- **ページの統一性がなくなる**

ページの統一感がなくなり人によっては読みにくいと感じるページになる可能性があります。また、原文と翻訳の結果になり回答としても長くなります。

---

- **翻訳してもらえない可能性がある**

以下の質問を見てください。日本語に翻訳する機会は十分に与えられ、回答も得ました。しかし、英語は英語のままで翻訳されることはありませんでした。誰かが編集してくれるという考えは甘いです。

[可変長引数関数のラッピング方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/11487/how-to-wrapping-variadic-function)
[twitter follower](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/10275/twitter-follower)
[可変長引数関数のラッピング方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/11487/how-to-wrapping-variadic-function)
[Herokuから確認メールを送信することができない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12098/could-not-send-a-confirmation-email-from-heroku)
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9992/prolog-how-can-i-output-the-results-within-the-designated-limits

---

- **英語でも綴りが違う場合があります。**

アメリカ英語とイギリス英語で綴りが違うことがあるようですが、どちらを推奨しますか
本当に些細なことです。こういったレベルでも話し合いの必要がありますが、その都度討議しますか？

---

- **過去の例を知っていますか**

以前メタで[日本人じゃないですけど、回答することができると思います。いいですか？](/q/1959)は記憶に新しいと思います。この方は、Australiaの方で、日本語で回答して頂いております。

> [画像読み込み時に Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture というエラー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/14550/%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E8%BE%BC%E3%81%BF%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB-bitmap-too-large-to-be-uploaded-into-a-texture-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC/14562#14562)

調べたところもうお一方、Australiaの方で、日本語での回答を頂いております。

> [Rubyで文字列と数字が混在している配列をソートする方法を教えてください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/69/ruby%E3%81%A7%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97%E3%81%A8%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%97%E3%81%8C%E6%B7%B7%E5%9C%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E9%85%8D%E5%88%97%E3%82%92%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95%E3%82%92%E6%95%99%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84/1759#1759)

また、英語の質問に対してこういったコメントもあります

> https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/8462/onapplicationquit-is-not-called-when-accepttcpclient-is-called-and-play-mode-fin#comment7650_8462
>   スタック・オーバフローへようこそ！このサイトは日本人のためだから、日本語に翻訳してください。 –  Andrew T. 3月27日 2:35

Indonesiaの方です。日本語でコメントを頂いております。

また、海外の教師の方が以下の質問をした例も日本語です。

> [変数名　漢字と仮名の字は大丈夫？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/8112/%E5%A4%89%E6%95%B0%E5%90%8D-%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97%E3%81%A8%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D%E3%81%AE%E5%AD%97%E3%81%AF%E5%A4%A7%E4%B8%88%E5%A4%AB)

このように海外の方々に日本語を尊重してもらっています

---

Comment: 個人的には、このサイトから英語を排除したいのではなく、**どちらにも投稿できるなら**英語版に投稿したがお互いやりやすいだろう、というのが英語の質問を別サイトに移動する一番の理由です。日本語版に投稿する理由が薄いとでも言いましょうか。一方で、日本語版にある質問には**日本語版でしか**回答できません。もちろん日本語で書かれていたほうがベターですが、何語であろうと（ソースコードぐらいは読めますし）有益になる可能性はあるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 質問を日本語で書くことを促しているのは **他国語だと（回答者が敬遠するために）有効な回答を得られる可能性が低い** からであって、「回答に他国語を許容するか」とは別問題だと思います。むしろ他国語の回答を排除してしまうと **せっかく解決方法を知っているのに教えられない（教えてもらえない）** と状況が発生してしまうのでもったいない気がします。
とはいえ、何語でもOKとするのもどうかと思うので、「日本語、英語」くらいが妥当ではないかと。

Comment: @unarist アスキーアードコードが透過されてアラビア語で質問されたとしたら私の環境では確実に豆腐と言語すら特定できない悲惨な状況になるかもしれませんプリプロセッサの質問ですかライブラリですがそれともエラーですか質問文は豆腐ですね素晴らしい質問じゃないですか投票してください広告します誰がプラスを入れます？

Comment: @ita_3y ちょうどいい具体的に過渡が書かれてるものを広告に掲げました。どれだけ素晴らし回答か評価してもらましょう。

Comment: ここは「 **英語で回答** しても構いませんか？」という質問への回答欄だがあなたは「日本語以外（の言語）」へと論点を広げすぎている。あなたは回答に使用されたら受け付けられない言語として「中国語、アラビア語、フランス語、ドイツ語、ロシア語」を挙げているが英語は許容できるのか？それをはっきりさせた上で「ある他言語をひとつでも追認すればなし崩し的にその他の言語も使用され混乱するかもしれない」という懸念を訴えてはどうだろうか

Comment: @user10678 全く反対の意見なのに回答の仕方を指摘頂いたおかげで回答を書き直すことが出来ました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 議論とは自身の意見を押し通すための争いでなく場にいる全員で判断材料を可能な限り絞り出し最良の選択肢を決めるものだと思う。だから反論はしないし良い意見にまとめる助力はする。あなたの回答は具体例が多く網羅的だが伝わりづらかった。今は理解しやすくなったと思う

Comment: @user10678 まだ、網羅できていない材料は自分の意見以外の選択肢です。英語まで含めれば情報の多さは認識しています。具体例としては学会、政治、標準化機構などを含めないといけないと思います。自動で翻訳してくれるシステムも紹介も含める事になると思います。しかし、カバーしきれない単語領域もあると言うのも事実でkinodynamicは日本語訳として適当なものは見つかっていません。これはそのまま利用する事になると単語です。英語の回答が読めるのだったらライセンスが読めたり、エラーが読めたり、コメントが読めたりすると思います。英語に対する、翻訳の不完全性や英語の回答を承認する質問者への疑惑やページの統一性の問題を完全に払拭できる判断材料が全くないのです。

Answer (score 9):

### TL;DR

ここは日本語版のStackOverflowなのですから、日本語で書かれた質疑応答知識が集約される場となることが存在意義であるはずです。すなわち回答は日本語でなされることが望ましいことは間違いないでしょう。その前提で、他言語での回答があった場合には、削除や移動、あるいはマイナス票を投ずるのではなく、その回答者に日本語訳も付けるようにコメントで依頼すれば充分だと考えます。

### 意見の理由など

まず @user10678 氏の

> [回答の本質は言語ではなくその内容である](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1991/10492)

には全面的に同意します。たとえ英語以外のフランス語、スペイン語、中国語、タガログ語…例を挙げればきりがありませんが、極端な話[クリンゴン語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B4%E3%83%B3%E8%AA%9E)で書かれていたとしても、提起された問題を解決できる内容であれば回答として成立します。回答の質は書かれた言語には依存しません。

しかしその一方で、他言語で書かれた回答を元の質問者ほか日本語版SOを訪れる人々（ほとんどが日本語話者でしょう）が理解できるのか、といった問題は残ります。英語であれば慣れている人もそこそこ多いでしょうが、それ以外の言語となると理解できる人の割合はかなり減ることが予想されます。

ところでよく考えて欲しいのですが、そもそもその他言語で回答をされた方は、日本語の質問を読んだうえで回答をしているのですから、少なくともある程度は日本語を理解する能力を持っていることが期待できるはずです。であるなら難しく考えることはなく、回答者に対するコメントで回答に日本語訳も付けるように日本語で依頼すれば良いのではないでしょうか。

その依頼を見て回答者が日本語訳を付けてくれればそれで済みます。訳に誤りがあればその旨コメントで指摘が入るでしょう。仮にそのまま日本語訳が付かなかった場合は、その言語を理解できる人が回答が有用であると判断すればプラス票を投じるでしょうし、その内容が多くの人に本当に役に立つものであれば日本語に訳そうと考える人も出てくるでしょう。それほどのものでもなければ誰にも内容を理解されないまま無視されて、他の回答の下に沈んでいくだけです。日本語が期待される場所に他言語で書く以上、その程度のハンデを背負うことはやむを得ないものと考えます。

Answer (score -3):

私は、

条件付きで　多言語投稿に、
賛同します。
"

元より、

より　広い、
意見の　交流は、
問題解決視点において、
有益だ、
と　思えるからです。
"

さて、

条件ですが、
サイト側が　表示に、
際して、
自動翻訳を　導入し、

閲覧者の　払う、
コストを　削減し、

言語の　境を、
払いのける　事です。
"

いうまでもなく、

個々の　観覧者が、
非母国語を　見る度に、
翻訳が　何らか、
行われる　ものと、
思われますが、

其の　回数たるや、
膨大な　回数に、
のぼる　事は、
不可避でしょう。
"

反面、

サイトが　能動的に、
翻訳を　済ませるならば、
大凡　1回で、
済むと　思えます。
"

併せて、

非母国語への　親好に、
阻害を　持つ、
ものにも　境なく、
情報が　齎され、

其の　発想を、
活かせる　事でしょう。
"

加えて、

将来的には　英語版との、
シームレスな　交流も、

其れ処が　全世界版への、
展開も、

視野に　入ってきます。
"

此は、

此の　サイト自身と、
ユーザに　とって、
素晴らしい　恩恵となる、
事でしょう。
"

しかしながら、

人族が　此に、
あたるならば、
遺憾ながらも　コスト高と
なってしまいます。
"

なればこそ、

他サイトで　申し訳ないが、
AutoDiscコミュニティーが、
過去　採用していたような、
「自動翻訳システムを、
導入する　事が、
最善、」
と、

帰結する　ものと、
考えます、

如何でしょうか？