# Can I post in English? / 英語で投稿してもいいですか？

Tags: サポート, よくある質問, 質問の仕方

- Can I post in English?

  - I have a question for Japanese programmers
  - Can I answer in English?
- 英語で投稿してもいいですか？

  - 英語の質問を投稿してしまいました
  - 英語版との見分け方は？

[←FAQ目次に戻る](/q/1484)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(日本語版は下にあります)

#### Welcome to Stack Overflow Japanese, O wielder of English!

We are Stack Overflow *for* Japanese speakers, so questions here should be in Japanese. Many of our visitors are not very good at English.

We recommend asking on https://stackoverflow.com/ instead.

> Since [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/) network has many Q&A sites, your question may not be appropriate to Stack Overflow. Please check [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) before asking on there.

#### But I want to tap into the wisdom of Japanese programmers (e.g. questions about Japanese software)

Asking in English is okay *if this site is more suitable* than Stack Overflow English.

However, please consider asking on the English site because:

- There are more Japanese people there than you think.
  <sub>Honestly, Stack Overflow in Japanese is not as popular as the English site among Japanese programmers.</sub>
- Your post may help other English speakers.

If you do decide to post here in English:

- **Explain why you're asking here.**

  - It will prevent close votes and many "Did you mean: stackoverflow.com" comments.
- **Please include a summary in Japanese with your question body.**
- **You don't have to translate the whole question to Japanese.**

  - In particular, keep in mind that attaching a machine translation result probably won't make your post any more understandable. Lots of details may get lost too.

#### Can I answer in English?

At a minimum, please include a summary in Japanese with your answer.

see also: [英語で回答しても構いませんか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1990/8000)

---

### 日本語が読み書きできる方へ

スタックオーバーフローへようこそ！

ここは**日本語で質問・回答する**ために作られたStack Overflowの姉妹サイトです。ぜひ日本語で質問・回答を投稿してください！

もし英語で質問したいという場合は、本家 https://stackoverflow.com/ をご利用ください。

- 英語版の内容そのままに、UIだけ日本語に翻訳したサイト
- 英語版の内容を翻訳しただけのサイト

は今のところ（公式には）存在しません。投稿もアカウントも英語版とは独立しています。

> Stack Exchange ネットワークには多くのQ&Aサイトが存在するため、日本語版SOで扱っている話題の中には、英語版では別サイトで扱うものもあります。自信がない場合は [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) をご確認ください。

#### 間違えて日本語版に投稿してしまいました

タイトルと本文を日本語に書き直していただければ、そのまま日本語版に残すことはできます。投稿の下にある `編集` というリンクから、タイトルや本文を編集することができます。

ただ英語版にも質問されるのであれば、その旨を記載したり、どちらかで解決したらもう片方にも解決策を投稿するなど、両方の質問できちんと対応をお願いします。それが面倒であれば、こちらの質問は削除してしまってもかまいません。

> もし「ここが英語版と紛らわしくて間違えてしまった。なんとかしてほしい」という要望があれば、[メタに投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)していただけると参考になります。

#### 英語版との違いは？

- URLの頭に `ja.` がついている
- ロゴの下に小さく「スタック・オーバーフロー」と書いてある
- UIが日本語になっている

のが日本語版です。

Comment: クローズ票の理由に、「英語です」を加えていただき、このページへのリンクを貼れたりしないでしょうか。。最近なぜか英語が多い。