# spresense の質問を英語でしたい / No main stack overflow spresense?

Tags: 討議

There is no support for English speakers.
Thankfully I can read this page with automatic translation...

A search for spresense on stackoverflow.com shows there is no support there.

May I ask a technical question in English on the Japanese stackoverflow?

---

和訳：

英語話者へのサポートがありません。
ありがたいことにページを自動翻訳することで読めているのですが……。

spresense を stackoverflow.com で検索してみたところ、サポートは無いようです。

日本語版スタック・オーバーフローにおいて、spresense の技術的質問を英語でしても構いませんか？

Comment: In the Japanese stack overflow, if you ask a question in English, do you expect the answer to be Japanese or English? / 日本語版スタックオーバーフローにおいて、あなたが英語で質問を行った場合、回答は日本語もしくは英語のどちらを期待していますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A search for spresense on stackoverflow.com shows there is no support there.

There is no reason why you can not become the first questioner. [Sony's official site](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/support/spresense-programming-support-on-stack-overflow/) has the following description.

> A team of Sony engineers scout Stack Overflow daily for new questions, and we take pride in helping third party developers as much as we can.
>
> ...
>
> 1. Go to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and write your question. Make sure to include the word "spresense".
> 2. Use the **sony** tag to highlight your question.

They seem to be waiting.

Comment: Thank you. I will try. Hopefully the English team can create a spresense account there too.

Comment: Unfortunately the people over there were too rude. I will ask my question on here in English in a simple way.

Comment: @AndrewKroll , It's a pity you felt the people over there _rude_. But each site has its own policy or local rules and you are requested to follow the rules, and that is clearly notated in the comment to your on-hold question. As explained in another answer of this thread, in Japanese スタック・オーバーフロー, you are requested to post a question at least having a summary in Japanese. Please have a little regard to our rules.

Comment: If I could read and write Japanese, I would. Unfortunately this is the only platform SONY uses to offer tech support, so please forgive the use of English. Also, I did follow the rules there, and I don't think they even read my post, since the reasons did not make any sense.

Comment: @AndrewKroll , If you cannot respect the community's rules, your question would not be respected. You should better contact to Sony explaining this sort of questions cannot be accepted in stackoverflow.com. And remember you once said _I can read this page with automatic translation_. Better try some translation service to make a summary in Japanese.

Comment: @AndrewKroll I don't know actual reasons why your question was closed, but it can be one of the reasons that your question is not related to programming strongly. Being different from Stack Overflow for Japanese, questions which is only related to hardware is off-topic on English Stack Overflow. See [this Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57998/341401) for details. Also, you can ask why your question is deleted on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) in English.

Comment: Andrew Kroll さん, if translating into Japanese is a problem, my method would be useful. I'm not good at English. When I ask a question in English, I do the following: 1) Automatically translate English questions into Japanese. 2) Automatically translate the translation result into English. 3) Check the translation result. If the result is as intended, end. If not, repeat steps 1) and 2).

Answer (score 3):

(English version follows.)

基本的には [Can I ask questions in English? / 英語で質問してもいいですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314/19110) に書いてある通りだと思います。

日本語版は日本語で運営されているので、英語の質問は推奨されていません。日本語に翻訳しての質問であれば OK かと思います。英語話者による日英併記もある程度許容されています。

また、本家においても現在タグが無いだけでプログラミングに関する質問をすることはできるかと思います。プログラミングではなくハードウェアに関係する場合、[その他のサイトが使えるかもしれません](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57998/341401)。

もし日本のユーザーに質問を見てもらいたいということであれば、英語で質問を書き、その要旨を手動翻訳の日本語で書くのが良いのではないでしょうか。

---

At first, please read [Can I ask questions in English? / 英語で質問してもいいですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314/19110).

Stack Overflow for Japanese is maintained mainly in Japanese, and asking questions in English is not so recommended. It may be OK to translate your question to Japanese by your own. Posting your question in English with a summary in Japanese is also OK.

Also, asking questions related to programming on Spresense may be on-topic on https://stackoverflow.com, although there is no Spresense tag currently. Other hardware questions which are not related to programming can be possibly asked on other sites. See [this Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57998/341401).