# メインサイトからメタサイトに移行したときのデフォルトタグが英語になっている

Tags: バグ

[No main stack overflow presence?](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2830/19110)

上の質問をメインサイトからメタサイトに移行 (migrate) したのですが、デフォルトで付くタグが [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) と英語になっています。和訳して [討議](/questions/tagged/%e8%a8%8e%e8%ad%b0) にして頂きたいです。