# 英語で投稿されようとしている質問を、未然に誘導する仕組みが欲しい

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了, 英語

英語で書かれた質問に対する自動的な対応処理が欲しいです。

日本語版スタック・オーバーフローが始まってから 4 年ほど経ちますが、英語で書かれた質問が未だに投稿されます。特にモデレーターの通報レビューキューに載せられる投稿の多くが英語投稿なので、上手く自動的に処理できるような仕組みが無いかなと考えています。多くの英語投稿は日本語話者が「英語を使わないといけない」と思って投稿されたもののように見えるので、ある程度自動処理できるのではないでしょうか。

ただし英語投稿の中にはそのようなものだけでなく、[理由があって英語で投稿されるもの](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2830/19110)が例外的に含まれます。このあたりをどう自動的に取り扱うかが難しいと私は感じています。

たとえば（可能であれば）質問投稿前の画面で質問が英語で書かれていることを自動検知して、英語投稿に関する FAQ へのポップアップを出すようにすれば良いのではないかと思うのですが、いかがでしょうか？

### 補足

- 過去に[類似の提案が為されている](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2523/19110)のですが、そちらでは英語質問の全面ブロックを提案しています。私の投稿ではそうではなく、投稿前に FAQ への導線を作ることを提案しています。
- To SE Team: Is it possible to automatically pop up a link to a FAQ page if a question may be written only in English? (e.g. if it doesn't contain any Hiragana letters [ぁ-ん].)

### 追記

- スペイン語版 Stack Overflow に類似の機能がついていると[教えて頂きました](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317116/your-community-s-current-problems-findings-and-initiatives/317206?noredirect=1#comment1041866_317206)。スペイン語になりますが、[こちらの投稿です](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2043)。
- 本家 Stack Overflow には逆に、スペイン語で投稿されようとしていたら検出してスペイン語版へ誘導する仕組みが[あるようです](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/325865/5989200)。

Comment: Could you please add the initiative to [the list on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317116/your-community-s-current-problems-findings-and-initiatives)?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky added!

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: この仕組みを応用すれば、回答に「ありがとう」が含まれている場合に注意を促す事も可能なのかなと思いました。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Shog9 さんおよび aki さんの回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2839/19110)を受けて、ポップアップメッセージの叩き台を考えました。以下の通り実装するのはいかがでしょうか？

1. 質問本文が空でないとき、本文フォームから別のフォームに移ったタイミングで本文に1文字も `[ぁ-ん]` 内の文字 (つまり、大体の平仮名のどれも) が含まれていない場合、ポップアップが出る (出るだけで、そのまま投稿はできる)。1文字以上含まれていれば特に何もしない。
2. ポップアップのメッセージ

   > If you would like to ask questions in English, please read [this FAQ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314) first. ／ 英語で質問したい場合、先に[こちらのFAQ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314)をご覧ください。
3. タイトルは加味しない。本文のみ。また、回答側には実装しない。

---

To SE Team: Would you implement a pop-up message as below?

1. If a question body is not empty and it does not contain any Hiragana `[ぁ-ん]` (< 1 letter), then a message is displayed just after moving from body form to another form.
2. Message:

   > If you would like to ask questions in English, please read [this FAQ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314) first. ／ 英語で質問したい場合、先に[こちらのFAQ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314)をご覧ください。
3. Only check for a question body, not for a title. Also, answers will not be checked.

### 追記

この機能は (部分的に) 実装されました。対応してくださった皆様、どうもありがとうございました！

出てくるメッセージの内容にやや問題があるため、そのことに関する別の投稿をしました　→　[投稿にひらがなが含まれていない場合のポップアップメッセージ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2856/19110)

Answer (score 4):

@Shog9 さんより回答をいただきました。

Yes, this is possible. Could do it for just titles, just body, or both.

I would need:

1. A minimum length for the text you would expect to be in Hiragana (at least 1 character, at least 10, etc)
2. A warning message to be displayed to the author
3. Preference on title, body, etc

---

可能です。ひらがな検知箇所については、タイトル、本文、もしくはタイトルと本文、から選べます。

以下が必要となります。

1. ひらがなの必要文字数（1文字以上、10文字以上、等）
2. 投稿者への表示メッセージ
3. タイトル、本文、もしくはタイトルと本文、のいずれか