# タイトルにタグを含んだ質問が投稿されようとしているとき、未然に誘導する仕組みが欲しい

Tags: 機能の要求

質問のタイトルにタグ的な表現を含んだ質問の投稿を自動的に処理する仕組みを希望します。

別個に「タグ」の仕組みは用意されているので、タイトルへのタグ的な表現は非推奨とされていますが、度々`[ ]`や`【】`をタイトルに含めた投稿を見かけます。

ほとんどの場合は投稿レビューでレビュアーによって編集されたり、またはコメントで指摘してくれているユーザーもいますが、人手をかけて毎回やるのも面倒です。

ある程度パターンが決まっているので、例えば「タイトルの**行頭**に`[`を含み、かつ`]`も含んでいる場合」などで簡単なメッセージ([ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)への誘導)を出せるとよいのかなと思います。

> 対象：質問のタイトル
>   パターン： `^[.+]`

**類似の仕組み (実施済み)**

- [英語で投稿されようとしている質問を、未然に誘導する仕組みが欲しい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2838/3060)

Comment: 関連: [Automatic removal of bracketed tags from question titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70498/341401)

Comment: 関連: [Automatically remove the patterns “tag :” and “tag -” from titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138321/341401)、および [Can we extend the automatic removal of tags in question titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142711/341401)

Comment: 参考: [Can we prevent titles with an unnecessary tag in them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103563/341401)に対する[Jeffの回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105991/341401)

Comment: 「自動で削除」や「タグに変換」もアイデアとしては考えましたが、あまりガチガチにやると「なぜ投稿できないの？」となりそうなので、まずはルールの周知ができればいいのかなと考えています。

Comment: @cubick こちらを [the list on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317116/your-community-s-current-problems-findings-and-initiatives)に追加いただくことは可能でしょうか?

Comment: 自動で削除するのも、メッセージを出すのも比較的容易なようですね。また、色んな括弧の正規表現指定もそこまで難しいことでもないようです。 https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50971590#50971590

Answer (score 8):

SOruではタグをつけようとした際にメッセージを出しているそうです。
[image: SOru Screen Shot from Nicolas]

確かにタグを自動で削除するのは文脈によっては「投稿したいのにできない」ともなりそうなので、
上記のようにメッセージを出してヘルプページの　[タグとは何ですか、どのように使用しますか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)　に誘導するなどが良いかと思います。（[ニコラスさんの受け売り](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50985982#50985982)ですが……）

また、括弧の種類も指定さえすれば正規表現で捕らえることも難しくは無いそうです。
私が勝手に想定している括弧の種類は以下だろうと思っています。

```
【】『』《》｢｣「」()（）[]［］<>＜＞
```

表示するメッセージを提案すればそれを反映できるそうです。
メッセージ案ですが、以下はどうでしょうか？

> タイトルで [Python] のような書き方をするのは避け、代わりに本文の下にあるタグ機能を使ってください。「Pythonで○○する方法」のように、タイトルだけで自然な文になるのが望ましいです。詳しくは [タグとは何ですか、どのように使用しますか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)  を確認してください。

Comment: +1: 「タイトルにタグを使用する」の「タグ」と「タグの使用を検討してください」の「タグ」とで意味が違って誤解を生みそうなので、次のようにするのは如何でしょうか：「タイトルで [Python] のような書き方をするのは避け、代わりに本文の下にあるタグ機能を使ってください。「Pythonで○○する方法」のように、タイトルだけで自然な文になるのが望ましいです。詳しくは（以下略）」

Comment: @nekketsuuu 一旦編集しました。ヘルプページでは`[タグ]`って言ってるし`[Python]`って具体的にタグ名出すのはどうかなぁと思ってましたが、別にそちらに習う必要はありませんでしたね。

Answer (score 5):

反対ではないですが、何を対象にするかは十分確認した上で実施してください。誤って問題の無いタイトルを排除するぐらいならやらない方がマシだと思います

- Webサーバー(Apache2.4)でmod_rewrite モジュールを読み込む方法を教えてください
- DNS レコードに設定されている、「IN」は何を表していますか?
- urlopen error [WinError 10054] 既存の接続はリモート ホストに強制的に切断されました　を解決したいです

とりあえず1ページ目に出てきたタイトルですが、当然これらは排除されてはいけません。ある程度の過去分は誤排除がないことを確認してください