# 日英併記の質問は許容される？

Tags: 討議, 日本語, 英語

日本語と英語で同じ内容を同時に説明している質問は許容されますか？
つまり、内容が日英併記された質問はオントピックでしょうか？

#### 具体例

- [「（日本語orEnglish）<question about opencv> How are the “left” and “right” values calculated in the haar cascade xml files?」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/35675/19110)

#### 関連

- [Can I ask questions in English? / 英語で質問してもいいですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314/19110)
- [英語で回答しても構いませんか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1990/19110)

Comment: もしオフトピックとするならどのような理由を想定していますか

Comment: @suzukis 英語で書かれている部分は本家 Stack Overflow に移すべきで、英語部分は編集で削除すべきだ、という意見があるかもしれないなと思って投稿しました。私自身は適当な条件の下、オントピックで良いんじゃないかと思っています。

Comment: ご自身でオフトピックにする理由が思いつかず、意見を求めたいことが別にあるのであれば、「オントピックか？」ではなく、意見を求めたいことを質問に記載されてはいかがでしょうか

Comment: @suzukis 「英語部分は削除すべきだ」という部分がオフトピックの理由になりうるという意味でした。また、「オントピックか？」と書いたことで、オントピックかオフトピックかの意見を募集しているつもりでした。通常のメタの使い方通り、upvote された回答を得て自分の意見を確かめたかったというだけです。混乱させてしまいすいません。自己回答しておけばよかったですね。

Comment: "「英語部分は削除すべきだ」という部分がオフトピックの理由になりうる"というような明確に誤った意見を期待する意図はなんでしょう？

Comment: @suzukis 私にとってそれは明らかじゃなかった、というだけだと思います。[「英語で質問してもいいですか？」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314/19110)の内容だけで判断できなかったので質問しました。実際、上で具体例として挙げた質問の再オープン票を入れてよいのか迷ったのです。これはメタの使い方として不適切でしょうか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu つまり質問者本人としてはオントピックであると考えているけれど、ひょっとするとオフトピックとして考える人がいるかもしれないので、もしオフトピックとして考える人がいるならばそれはどんな理由か？ということを聞きたかったということですよね。`「英語部分は削除すべきだ」`はひょっとするとこのような考えがあるかもしれないとして、例をあげたものと推測します。討議として間違っているとは思いませんので、メタの使い方として適切だと思います。オフトピックとして考える人がいなければ、それも結論になる得るでしょうし。

Comment: メモ： 英語併記部分が削除編集された投稿です。 [「CNNで動物の顔を認識させるにあたり、活性化関数にはソフトマックスとシグモイドのどちらが良いですか？」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/36262/19110)

Answer (score 5):

大前提として、質問者が日本語に堪能でなく英語を併記する必要があるならばオントピックという立場です。

しかし[件のリビジョン１](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/35675/1)を見てもらえばわかりますが、この質問は英語で投稿されています。この時点で、ツアーを読んでおらず、タグ等による類似質問を確認していないことがほぼ確実です。これは回答者や他の閲覧者を軽視する姿勢であり、個人的にはその時点でオフトピックにしたいです（この点は極端に個人的な思想なので、賛同を求めるわけではありません）。

その後、取り繕うように日本語が併記されただけに過ぎず、質問者が当初から望んでいた姿ではありません。件の質問以外には日英併記の質問はないに等しく、議論する意義があるのか疑問です。

それよりは、英語のみの投稿をシステム的に対処できないでしょうか？ 例えば、質問文に日本語が含まれていない場合は「質問を投稿する」ボタンが「投稿せずツアーを再学習する」ボタンに変わる等。
システム的な対処により英語質問がブロックされれば、日英併記の質問も淘汰されるのではないでしょうか？

suzukisさんの提案を受け、[英語質問のシステム的ブロック](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2523/4236)を提案しました。

Comment: 「取り繕うように日本語が併記されただけ」という部分に違和感を感じます。元の質問の英文と日本語文を見て、日本語文の方が上手で丁寧だという印象を持ちました。この質問者は、日本語の方が上手に扱え、できるなら日本語で質問したかったが、何かの勘違いで仕方なく英語で質問したのではないでしょうか? 英語質問のシステム的なブロックについては私は賛成です(これにより「何かの勘違い」がなくなれば、と思います)。

Comment: システム的に対処する、の部分に非常に同意します。

Comment: 英語のみの投稿をシステムとして制限すべきだ、という提案は別にポストされた方がいいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: @masm さん、私も「何かの勘違いで‌​仕方なく英語で質問した」と思います。日本語に編集するよう指示されても英語を消すことなく、照れ隠し的な行動で日英併記したため「取り繕うように」と表現しました。

Answer (score 4):

一意見として回答します。

質問が日本語で記載されており、かつ回答可能であればオフトピックとする必要はないと思います。
おそらく細かいニュアンスとしては英文の方が正しくなりそうですが、回答がつく中でそれらのニュアンスはアジャストされていくかと思います。
結果的に質問と回答が日本語で成立すれば、Q&Aとしては問題ないと思いました。
ただし、英文の方は本家StackOverflowで質問するようにコメントで誘導し、日本版には本家StackOverflowへのリンクを記載するのが適切かと感じます。

なので私の結論としては、以下となります。

**・オントピックで問題ない

・本家StackOverflowで英文を質問するように誘導する

・日本版から参照できるようにリンクをつけてもらう**

Answer (score 3):

英語部分を削除すべきかという質問ならともかく、オントピックか、と言われるとオフトピックでないことは自明なのでなにが聞きたいのかわからなかったのですが、編集とクローズについての違いの認識が不十分なことが原因のようです。

> 「英語部分は削除すべきだ」という部分がオフトピックの理由になりうる

「英語部分は削除すべきだ」というのは、質問を編集すべきかどうか、という問題です。クローズは、第三者の編集では改善出来ない問題がある質問について、一時的に回答を制限することで質の低い回答が集まることを規制しつつ、質問者自身で改善を促し、または将来削除するための機能です。

編集で改善出来ることは編集で改善すればよいのであって、クローズ理由を探す必要はありません。