# 英語質問のシステム的ブロック

Tags: 機能の要求, 却下

英語での質問がちょくちょく舞い込みます。

- [Python programming](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/36107/1)
- [[DirectX12]How Can I get The GPU backbuffer?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/36083/1)
- [< question about opencv > How are the “left” and “right” values calculated in the haar cascade xml files?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/35675/1)

このような投稿者はツアーを読んでおらず類似質問も確認していない可能性が高く、自分勝手な質問者と考えられます。

そこで提案なのですが、日本語文字を含まない質問はシステム的にブロックできないでしょうか？
日本語文ではほぼ確実にひらがなが含まれますので正規表現 `[あ-ん]` でテストすることを希望します。また可能であれば日本語文字を含まないまま投稿を試みる質問者にはツアーへの誘導も併せて希望します。

参考： [日英併記の質問は許容される？ の回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2514/4236)

---

[英語で投稿されようとしている質問を、未然に誘導する仕組みが欲しい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2838/4236)が実施されましたが、相変わらず定期的に英語質問が投稿されます。
それらほぼすべてが、日本語に修正されたりすることなくクローズされ消えていきます。
やはりシステム的にブロックするのが適切ではないでしょうか？

---

相変わらず定期的に英語質問が投稿されます。それらほぼすべてが、日本語に修正されたりすることなくクローズされている印象なのですが、気のせいでしょうか？ （Data Explorerで追跡できたりしますかね…？）
このような繰り返しは生産性がなく不快です。[Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)に基づき、英語質問をシステム的にブロック、つまり投稿そのものを拒絶することを希望します。

質問とは逆に、回答においては英語投稿はほとんど見られず、もし存在したとしても有益な回答だと思います。しかし、回答入力過程において先にコードを貼り付ける等、一時的に英語のみな状態にもなりますが、そのタイミングで「日本語が含まれていない」と警告されるのも不快です。回答入力に関しては警告を外すことを提案します。

現状、質問投稿フォームは日本語UIしか用意されていないはずで、にもかかわらず英語質問が絶えないということは、フォームの記載は一切読まず、入力ボックスらしきエリアに入力を行い、ボタンらしきUIをクリックしているだけと思われます。画面上のアドバイス・警告を全て無視する投稿者が一定数いることを意味しています。「質問を投稿する」ボタンが押せなくなることが重要と考えています。

---

却下されたとして英語質問が絶えない問題は解消されないんですよね…。

- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/89078/why-deep-canonical-correlation-analysis-is-not-adopted-in-sota-method
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/89091/shouldnt-eth-have-used-pos-from-the-beginning-why-they-used-pow-at-first

---

[英語質問に対して、英語回答が付く事態](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/90648/4236)まで発生してしまいました。質問者の自動生成されたアイコンはひらがなの「い」であり、日本語話者の可能性が高いです。にもかかわらず、クローズ理由を読むことなく、英語回答を受けて英語コメントまで書いている有様です。
**本当に英語質問を受け付けることは害悪でしかありません。**

上でも述べましたが、英語質問が問題なのではありません。日本語の入力フォームに英語で質問を入力する時点で、目をつぶっていて何もかも見ておらずく、**有害な質問者の可能性が極めて高い**ことが問題です。
（クロスポストを投稿する質問者も同様の傾向が極めて高いです。）

Comment: 参考: このご提案から暫く後に提案された別の投稿をきっかけに、英語質問に対してポップアップを出す機能が実装されました。 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2838/19110

Comment: 以前に、[オフトピックの中でも、どのような理由によりクローズされたのかを知る方法は？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3629/32986)という質問を投稿しました。この投稿へいただいた [rene さん](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/34532/rene)のコメントによれば、現状では本文が英語だったためクローズされた質問を、 Data Explorer で探すことはできないようです。

Comment: また、本質問で要求されているブロック機能には、かねてより賛成です。今回の場合で、特段ブロックを避けるような積極的な理由は見当たりません。むしろ、誤って英語で投稿してしまう質問者や、それに対処するユーザーやモデレーターの手間を減らせる点で、有益だと感じます。

Comment: 補足1: 信用度が10,000以上あれば 10k-Tools の [クローズ理由の統計](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days) ページで詳細を確認できますが、英語質問のクローズは 60% 以上あり、コミュニティにとっても少なくない負担だと感じます (編集や再オープン率も同ページで確認できます)。 / 補足2: 英語版においては質問中のコード部分が Markdown として適切にインデントまたはマークアップされていないとエラーで弾かれるというコメントも見かけました。バリデーションチェックのような仕組み自体は技術的に可能だと考えられます。

Answer (score 6):

[却下](/questions/tagged/%e5%8d%b4%e4%b8%8b)

提案時から時間も経ち、機能追加等で状況も変わってきているので別回答を提示しておきます。

---

2020 年 02 月頃に "新しい質問ページ" の機能が [リリース](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3274) され、「質問を投稿」しようと送信ボタンを押しても直接送信されるのではなく、ワンクッションおいて簡単な投稿内容のチェックが走るようになりました。

標準だと未記入項目が無いかなどのチェックだけですが、この部分で「本文が英語のみ」かのカスタムチェックを実施すれば、英語質問を未然に防ぐことが出来そうな気がします。

Comment: そのカスタムチェックでシステム的にブロック可能なのでしょうか？ そうであればぜひ実現してほしいです。現状、１回「質問をレビューする」を押せば次は条件を満たしていなくても「質問を投稿する」が有効化されていて、ブロックされないような印象で、実態がよくわかりません…。理想的には条件を満たさない場合はボタンを押せなくしてほしいですが…。

Answer (score 5):

ブロックまでしなくとも、英語サイトへの導線を提示してあげる事は可能じゃないかなと思います。

スタックオーバーフローのトップページに未登録の状態でアクセスすると、(クリックで閉じる事ができる)簡単な説明がバナーで表示されます。こちらと同じような仕組みで、ブラウザの`Accept-Launguage`をチェックして日本語以外のユーザがアクセスした場合には

- ここは主に日本語でのやり取りを想定したサイト
- 英語での質問は本家サイトの方が適しています

という一文を表示してあげる…というのは如何でしょうか。

Comment: 議論の発端は日本語の方が得意と思われる質問者が英語で質問することへの対処でしたので、英語サイトへの誘導はあまり意識していませんでした。そもそも「スタック・オーバーフロー」は日本語フォームしか用意されていないようですし。また類似質問を確認していない可能性が高い点についてはどうでしょうか？ 確認すれば否応なしに日本語でのQ&Aを目にするわけですが、確認しないような質問者はアドバイス程度の記述では読まないように感じます。とはいえ、投稿フォームの全般的な改善もそれはそれで必要に感じました。例えば翻訳が微妙なところがありますね。

Answer (score 0):

#### Stack Exchange サイト間では質問の移行が可能です

SEサイト間で質問を移行することがモデレーターには可能です。次のように実行します。質問のページから → クローズ → コミュニティ特有の理由 → この質問は Stack Exchange ネットワークの別のサイトに属しています → 移行先サイトの名前を入力します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ただし、いくつか問題があるかもしれません。以前、ロシア語版 Stack Overflow にて英語で投稿された質問を、英語版 Stack Overflow へ全て移行しようと試みたことがありました。そこで移行された質問の中にはいくつも低品質なものがあったため、英語版SOのモデレーターがフラストレーションを感じてしまうという問題に直面しました。英語版SOのモデレーターは、ロシア語版SOのモデレーターに、移行するのではなくそのように品質の低い質問をクローズするように依頼しました。すると、ロシア語版SO側では、英語で投稿された質問を低品質でクローズすることについて、主な問題は言語であったために少し奇妙に感じとられてしまいました。

#### カスタムクローズ理由

その結果、ロシア語版 Stack Overflow ではロシア語以外で書かれたすべての質問をクローズすることにしました。そのために新しいカスタムクローズ理由を追加しました:

> [ロシア語版 Stack Overflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)  はロシア語の質問のみを受け入れるため、この質問はクローズされました。質問をロシア語に翻訳するか[英語版 Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) を利用してください。

クローズ理由はロシア語で書かれており、コミュニティ特有のクローズ理由ポップアップに表示されています。

#### 正規表現チェック

タイトル、本文、またはタグのフィールドに何が存在するのかをシステムにチェックさせ、ユーザーに警告を表示する方法があります ([スペイン語版 Stack Overflow での議論はこちら](https://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/3299/10))。しかし、逆ができるかどうかは不明で、何が存在しないのかを確認することが可能かどうかはわかりません。

私は個人的にはこのアプローチが好みではありません。なぜなら、チェックする可能性のあるすべてのこととそれらの組み合わせを考えることは簡単な作業ではないからです。

#### 質問の翻訳

英語で書かれた質問の投稿者を助けることは可能です。Stack Overflow は Wiki のようなプラットフォームですので、テキストに問題があればそれを修正することが奨励されています。必要に応じて、英語から日本語に質問を翻訳することが可能です。

Comment: 今回の要望はシステム的な **自動での** ブロックであり、提案の方法だといずれもユーザーが目視でチェックしなければならず目的に合致しません。また、カスタムクローズ理由や正規表現でのチェックは既に利用しているはずです。

Answer (score -5):

こちらのタグのステータスを[却下](/questions/tagged/%e5%8d%b4%e4%b8%8b)に更新しました。開発者に本件が実装される可能性について確認いたしましたが、彼らによると平仮名だけでなくその他の一般的な言語検出における解決策については近い将来には何も予定されていないとのことでした。

Comment: 他の言語でも同様の需要はあるような気がしますが、どう対応されているのか気になりました。それとも自国語サイトに英語で投稿するのは日本人特有の行動なのでしょうか？ ともあれ、[cubickさんが提案しているカスタムチェック](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3682/4236) では実現できないのでしょうか？ やはり警告するだけでブロックする機能はない？

Comment: @sayuri コメントくださりありがとうございます。Rosie さんに再度確認いたしましたが、cubickさんが提案されたカスタムチェックは実施できないとのことでした。実装に至らず本当に申し訳ありません。