# オフトピックの中でも、どのような理由によりクローズされたのかを知る方法は？

Tags: サポート, 機能の要求, data-explorer

オフトピックというクローズ理由のなかにも、色々なクローズ理由があると思います：

- この質問は、スタック・オーバーフローについてヘルプセンターで定義されている範囲から外れているようです。
- 当サイト (ja.stackoverflow.com) は Stack Overflow (stackoverflow.com) とは独立して日本語の質問を扱うサイトとして運営されています。詳しくは、 Can I ask questions in English? / 英語で質問してもいいですか？ をご覧ください。この質問を日本語に編集していただければ、引き続きこのサイトで扱うことができます。英語で質問をするには、Stack Overflow へ新しく質問を投稿する必要があります。

[こちらの投稿](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678)によれば、 PostHistory テーブルの Comment フィールドに格納されている番号によって、クローズ理由の判別ができるようです<sup>[[1]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678)</sup>。しかし、前述のようにオフトピックの中にも種類があるため、 Comment フィールドはそういった場合には使えないと思います。

そこで質問ですが、もし「質問文が英語だったこと」がクローズ理由の質問を Stack Exchange Data Explorer で取得したいとき、どのようにすれば良いでしょうか？また、もしそういった機能が無い場合、その追加を希望します。

> ### PostHistory<sup>[[1]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678)</sup>
>
> - `Comment`: This field will contain the comment made by the user who edited a post.
> - If PostHistoryTypeId = 10, this field contains the CloseReasonId of the close reason (listed in `CloseReasonTypes`):
>   <sub>***Old close reasons:***
>
>   1 = Exact Duplicate
>
>   2 = Off-topic
>
>   3 = Subjective and argumentative
>
>   4 = Not a real question
>
>   7 = Too localized
>
>   10 = General reference
>
>   20 = Noise or pointless (Meta sites only)
>
>   ***Current close reasons:***
>
>   101 = Duplicate
>
>   102 = Off-topic
>
>   103 = Unclear what you're asking
>
>   104 = Too broad
>
>   105 = Primarily opinion-based</sub>

Comment: Related / similar on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297750/please-add-the-individual-close-as-off-topic-reason-in-the-data-explorer

Answer (score 2):

クローズされた質問に表示されるメッセージは英語だと "post notices" と呼ばれており、この部分はページを表示したユーザーに応じてより適切な内容が表示されるような仕組みになっています。

[New post notices: Improving feedback on Stack Overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/05/new-post-notices-improving-feedback-on-stack-overflow-questions/)

具体的には…

- 質問者本人には「次に何をすればよいか」をメインに
- モデレーターや "十分な信用度を持つ" ユーザーには詳しいクローズ理由や投票者の情報を
- それ以外のユーザーには必要最低限の情報のみ

データとしては残っているので恐らく SEDE でも引き当てることができると思うのですが、私自身が SEDE や SQL について詳しくないので、細かな説明は割愛します。(もし調べて分かったら追記します)

Comment: While they appear as postnotice on the post, the close notices are not stored in the PostNotices table as found in SEDE. I had to verify in case this changed recently but can confirm they are not there: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1444186

Answer (score 2):

別解として、SEDE ではありませんが直近でのクローズされた質問の統計を [レビューツール](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats) から確認することができます。(アクセスには一定の信用度が必要)

上記ページでは理由を含めたクローズ理由の統計を表示できますが、データは最長でも 90 日間までのようです。

---

レビューツールへの導線が分かりづらいので念のため説明しておくと、画面右上の「レビューキュー」アイコンをクリックして表示されたメニューから「ツール」の文字をクリック。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

次のページで下の方にスクロールすると "リンク" のセクションに「クローズされた質問の統計」があり、こちらを開けば OK です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

MSE に同様の要望が出されていますが、2022-05 現時点では未実装のようです。
(スタッフによる "延期" や "却下" のタグ付けも無し)

[Please add the individual close-as-off-topic reason in the Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297750)