# 投稿にひらがなが含まれていない場合のポップアップメッセージ

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了

以前の投稿 [英語で投稿されようとしている質問を、未然に誘導する仕組みが欲しい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2838/19110) で提案した機能要求が受理され、SE Team の方々によって、投稿本文にひらがなが含まれていない場合、以下のメッセージが warning として出るようになりました。

> If you would like to ask questions in English, please read [this FAQ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314) first. ／ 英語で質問したい場合、先に[こちらのFAQ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314)をご覧ください。

この仕組みは既にサイトへ実装されています。是非ご確認ください！

#### 問題点

ただし実装の都合上、質問の場合も回答の場合も同じメッセージが出ることになりました (元々は質問の場合だけにポップさせるつもりでしたが、そうできなかったとのことです)。そうなると、現状のメッセージでは以下の理由で困ります。

- ソースコードしか含まれていない回答を投稿しようとすると「英語が～」というメッセージが出てしまう。
- 英語での回答は[議論を呼んでいる](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1990/19110)部分であり、現状ある程度認められているので、やや的外れなメッセージが出てしまう。
- 今のメッセージは「質問」に特化したものであり「回答」のことを考えていない。

この制約に対応するためポップアップメッセージを書き換えたいのですが、どのように書き換えるのが良いでしょうか？

(あるいは、この問題に対処できる「ひらがな」以外の検出方法のアイディアがありましたら、是非教えて頂きたいです <(_ _)>)

Comment: メモ: [Can I ask questions in English?](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314/19110) には一応 "Can I answer in English?" の欄があります。ここをちゃんと書けば質問と回答両方には対応できそうです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 今のメッセージは「質問」に特化したものであり

英語での「質問・回答」をしたい場合、または「投稿」をしたい場合、でよいのではないでしょうか。

> ソースコードしか含まれていない回答を投稿しようとすると

あくまで今回実装された機能はワーニング(注意を促す)レベルで、投稿そのものをブロックするわけではないはずです。注意書きを読んだ上で投稿するかはユーザー自身の判断に任せれば大丈夫じゃないでしょうか。
(人間を相手にしているのだから、ソースコードをただ貼るだけじゃなくひとこと程度の日本語コメントは欲しいところです)

Comment: 「投稿」に一票。若干、不自然になる場面があるかも知れませんが、このような事を含めてコミュニティーの意思決定に委ねるならば細部まで整合したサイトを運営するのは不可能なので、まあ妥協も必要かと思います。

Comment: 「If you would like to post in English, please read this FAQ first. ／ 英語で投稿したい場合、先にこちらのFAQをご覧ください。 」に変更完了です。