# 英語による質問への対処法

Tags: 討議

日本語版にも、ちらほらと英語による質問が見られます。
これに対する対処方法といいますか、ポリシーのような物は定まっていないようで、 対応はその度にまちまちです。

多くの質問者は単に間違っているのだと思います。
日本語版には「日本語版」などの表記がないため、StackOverflowという一つのサイトが多言語化されているのだと理解するのは自然です。

マイナス票が集中するような事があれば気の毒ですし、淡々と対処できるように対処法・ポリシーをやんわりとでも決めておくと良いと感じます。

関連しそうな質問:

- [英語の質問は英語版の方へ移行できますか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1933/)
- [日本語のソフトウェアに関する質問が英語で寄せられた場合](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1815/)

Comment: 「日本語版」が書かれていないのは日本語の文字を使うと日本語と分かるためでした。もちろん、当コミュニティは日本語のソフト等に関連する英語の質問を回答したかったらできるだけ支援しますが、英語喋らないユーザーが多いのでルールを作ってもマイナス票が集まる気がします。

Comment: ちょっとイレギュラーなのですが、質問ではなく回答の場合はどうしましょうか？( http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/18560/ )

Comment: @Sieg 英語の回答に関しては、英語は苦手なので自分で英語で質問したり、沢山の英語を読んで調べる事は出来ないけれど、要点の解説くらいならば英語でも読めるから歓迎する、という質問者も多いと思います。ですので許容して放置でよいと思います。ただ、「日本語のQ&A」の蓄積という目的からすると、誰かが日本語で補足したり、翻訳してくれれば理想ですね。

Comment: 「これ位読め」とばかりに英文の引用を貼りつけているだけのコメントや回答がまれにありますが、あれに関してはあまり良くないとは思います。ただ、そんな物でも役には立つ面も多いので、その都度の評価に委ねる形でしょうか。

Comment: 関連: [英語の投稿を訳してしまっても良い？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2309/19110)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

個人的な意見としては、英語版への移動よりクローズの方が好ましいと考えています。

英語話者が間違えてこのサイトに投稿してしまったにせよ、日本語話者が英語で書いてしまったにせよ、StackExchangeのシステムに不慣れな方が多いように思います。英語版にアカウントを持っていない人も少なくないです。そのような状況で質問を移動してしまうと、「よくわからないままに質問を別サイトに移動されてしまった」という印象になりませんか？

また、StackExchangeサイト間の移動には [Don't migrate crap!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) というルールがあり、システム上も**移動先のサイトでクローズされると移動がキャンセルされる**という仕様になっています。そうなると質問者自身で（改善の上）投稿しなおしてもらうことになりますが、だったら最初から自分で英語版に投稿しなおしてもらったほうがわかりやすいでしょう。

このサイトが日本語で質問をする場であり、日本語に書き直すか英語版に投稿しなおしてほしい、というのが重要なのですから、その旨を伝えて質問者自身に判断してもらい、それまでこの質問はオフトピックだということを明示するために一旦クローズするというのがいいのではないでしょうか。おまけとして、モデレーターの手を借りずに実行できるという利点もあります。

Comment: [専用のクローズ理由](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/2323/3054)も用意され、基本的にはクローズという運用になったと思いますので、解決済みといたします。

Answer (score 1):

### 英語質問のパターン

英語の質問には以下の数パターンが見られます。

（以下では[本家StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)を「英語版」とし、[スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)を「日本語版」とします）

#### 1. 日本特有の事情（日本語の扱い、日本製のソフトウェアなど）についての英語の質問

日本語話者による回答を期待して、日本語版に質問したものと思われます。

#### 2. 質問者本人が英語版に、同じ質問をしている英語の質問

広く回答を得たいのでしょう。

#### 3. 質問者本人が同時に、日本語でも同じ内容の質問をしている英語の質問

広く回答を得たいので両方の言語で書いたのでしょう。
サイトが分かれている事を理解していないため、両方とも日本語版に投稿したものと思われます。

#### 4. その他の英語の質問

単に間違えたもの。

---

### 考えられる対処のパターン

これらの質問への対処にもそれぞれ以下の何パターンか考えられます。

#### A. 許容し放置

#### B. 英語版への移行をモデレータに依頼する

#### C. オフトピックなどで「改善待ち」にし、日本語に直すことを促す

#### D. 重複やオフトピックでクローズ

---

各質問のパターン毎に、考えられる対処法の内、どれが良いのかをあらかじめ議論し選択しておけば以後スムーズに対処出来ると思います。

編集を歓迎します。

Comment: 「案」とありますが、選択肢の例示ということでいいでしょうか。あと、「移行」と「オフトピックでクローズ」はそれぞれモデレータの権限とユーザーの行動で視点が違うので、「オフトピックでクローズされたのでモデレータが移行する」という行動もあり得ます。関連が深いので同時に議論しても良いのですが、取り得る選択肢の検討としては区別した方がよいと思います。

Comment: 分かりづらいですね。選択肢の例示のつもりでした。編集でましになっていれば幸いです。他の選択肢などあれば、ぜひ追加していただきたいのでwikiにしました。また、表現は全てユーザの視点に直しました。議論もユーザの行動を中心にするのが分かりやすいかなと思います。ユーザの行動を受けて、モデレータの方に動いていただく事もある、という形で。