# 英語の投稿を訳してしまっても良い？

Tags: 討議

たまに英語の投稿があり、中には外国の方もいらっしゃいますが、大半が日本人によるものと感じています。その様な質問に対しては大概コメントで、訳すか英語版で聞いてくれ、とお伝えしていますが、質問内容が適切であり手に負える範囲であれば日本語訳を追加してしまっても構わないでしょうか。
また良い場合、原文の英語（特にタイトル）はどうするべきだとお考えでしょうか。

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### 質問者が日本語話者の場合、翻訳には反対です

こういった質問は本家（英語版）の利用者の多さに期待して英語で書いたものの、投稿先を間違えた物と思われます。
これを翻訳してしまうと、ありがた迷惑ではないかと。
せっかく（苦労して？）英語で書いたのに、日本語版に引き込まれる形になり、質問者としては「何だかなー」という感じでしょう。

失敗に気付いて本家に投稿し直したとすると、日本語版とのマルチポスト状態になりますから、これのメンテの手間も生まれます。
質問者本人にその気がなかったとしたら、この手間の負担を求めるのは厳しいと思います。

#### 質問者が日本語を解さない場合は、翻訳が有意義だと思います

こういった質問はあまり見ないですが、日本語特有の問題なので日本語版に期待した、というパターンでしょうか。
（それでも、本家でやってもらうのがよい気もしますが……）

翻訳するにしても、リアルタイムで全文に行なうのは負担が大きそうなので、

- タイトルの一部と、質問の上部に日本語で簡単な要約を付記する程度の編集
- 英語のまま進行し、解決するなどの区切りが付いた時に対訳方式で翻訳を入れる

などが無難と感じます。

---

英文を削除して履歴に押し込めてしまうのには反対です。

編集履歴には元々、情報の訂正や追加、書式の改善などがあります。
それに翻訳作業やその訂正が加わる事になります。
これを、日本語が解らない（英語も母語とは限らず、やっとの思いで読み書きしているかもしれない）質問者が読みとき、自分の質問が現在どういう状態なのか理解するのは無理です。
また、日本語が解らない人にとってこそ必要なQ&Aになるかも知れないのに、最終的に残るのが日本語100％というのも残念な結果です。

Comment: 質問者が日本語話者かどうかをどう見極めるかと言う問題は残ってますけどね・・・ウチの近所には日本人っぽい名前で日本語まったく喋れない人とか、アッチ系の名前だけど日本語しか喋れない人とかいろいろいます。果たして現実的に可能なのかどうか。

Comment: @774RR  重要なのは、誤爆なのかどうか、つまり質問者の意思ですから、判然としない場合は本人に聞けば済むと思います。日本語版に誤爆したのであれば、質問者が非日本語話者であっても、日本語話者と同じあつかいでいいですね。私の書き方がポイントをはずしてしまっていたかも知れませんが、質問者の属性に拘るような意図ではないです。

Answer (score 3):

質問に回答が付かなければならないということもないので、英語のまま放置するに１票。
そのうち誰かがマイナス vote するでしょうし、マイナス vote された質問は
モデレートシステムによって一定時間経過後に削除されてしまう、のだと理解しています。

---

任意の読者が、当該質問が理解できて回答が用意できるのであれば
｢回答を投稿するのと同時に質問を編集する」前提で、
翻訳してしまってよいと思います。これなら「役に立つＱ＆Ａ」になります。

単に質問を翻訳しても回答が無ければ「役に立つＱ＆Ａ」にはならないわけで。

Answer (score 3):

**個人的には良い質問であれば積極的に日本語訳を追加すべきだと思います。**
Stack ExchangeはただのQ&Aサイトというよりは、良質な情報をコミュニティ主導で蓄積・提供するためのサイトだと思っています。[自分の質問に回答することが推奨されていて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)、[コミュニティWiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)などの機能があるのもそのためだと認識しています。
良質なQ&Aの蓄積が目的なのであれば、言語が日本語以外であっても、良い質問であればそれを積極的に訳して回答を求めるほうがサイトの趣旨に合っていると自分は思います。

また訳を追加する場合、元のタイトルと原文は質問内部に残すべきだと思います。