# 英語の質問を日本語に訳してはいけないか？

Tags: 討議, 編集

私は英語で投稿された[この質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/37685/iterate-and-sum-list-python)を日本語に編集したのですが、却下されました。
却下理由として、以下のものが書かれていました。

1. まずは英語で質問したいか日本語で質問したいかどうかを質問者さんに意思確認すべきだと思います。
2. 投稿者は英語しか理解できないと思われるので、日本語で回答を求めてるよりも、本家のStackOverflowに質問するように促した方がいいと思います。

「この質問を書き換えてヘルプセンターの規則を満たすようにすることができる場合は、質問を編集してください。」とアラートが出てるから翻訳したのに、編集内容以外の理由で却下されて不服なんですが、このサイトってこういうものですか？

ちなみに、「質問者さんに意思確認すべきだと思います。」と言われましたが、信用度の問題で僕にはできません（これを書いた人が意思確認すればいいのに）。

Comment: 関連？：[Can I ask questions in English? / 英語で質問してもいいですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2314/)　※編集よりクローズが良いと考えている人もいるかも

Comment: 関連 [英語の投稿を訳してしまっても良い？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2309/3974)

Answer (score 4):

1つ目の理由で却下したのは私です。

今回の場合、やはり却下されるべきだったと思います。元投稿の意図が失われる可能性があったからです。つまり、回答を日本語で欲しているか英語で欲しているかという意味で、質問者の意図を失っている可能性がありました。このため、編集に先立って意思確認すべきだ、というコメントをつけさせて頂きました。（ちなみに「元投稿の意図が失われる」というのは「編集の提案」に対するデフォルトの却下理由の1つです。）

「この質問を書き換えて〜」はどちらかと言うと質問者ご本人への通知で、「質問に答えてほしかったら改善してね」くらいの意味合いだと思います。クローズされた場合の改善はあくまで質問者がするものだと私は考えています。

追伸： 信用度が低くて自分には行えないが行いたいことは、メタやチャットに投稿すると、信用度が高い方に作業を依頼することができます。実際、タグシノニムの提案は現状[メタに投稿する形で行われることが多いです。](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B0%E3%82%B7%E3%83%8E%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A0%E3%81%AE%E6%8F%90%E6%A1%88%20is%3Aquestion)