# 質問者さんの同意がとれぬまま行われた質問の和訳編集をロールバックしてよい？

Tags: 討議, 翻訳, 編集

先日投稿された以下の質問は、英語でのご質問だったためオフトピックとしてクローズされました。

- [サービスのロゴをツールバーに表示する方法 / can't indicate Logo on Toolbar](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/47166/19110)

クローズされたあと、匿名 IP ユーザーから和訳編集の提案があり、数名の方がこれを承認したため Community ユーザー名義の編集が行われました。

しかし、この編集が質問者さんの意図通りであるか確認がとれません。mjy さんがコメントで書いてくださっている通り、日本語へ翻訳して質問を続けるか否かは質問者さんの判断に任せるべきと思います。過去のメタ投稿[「英語の投稿を訳してしまっても良い？」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2309/19110)や[「英語の質問を日本語に訳してはいけないか？」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2556/19110)もあわせてご覧ください。

このポリシーを貫くとすれば、この和訳編集はロールバックすることになります。とはいえ複数の方の承認によって為された編集ですので、勝手にロールバックして編集合戦になることも避けたいです。そこであらかじめメタに投稿してご意見を伺おうと思い、投稿しました。

- <del>この和訳編集をロールバックしても良いでしょうか？</del>　→　(追記) 別のIDの方によって[同じ内容の質問が投稿されている](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/47189/19110)ことが分かりました。これに伴い、和訳は和訳のまま放っておいて、元英語版の方を再オープンした後重複としてクローズしても良いでしょうか？
- もし質問者さんご本人がいらっしゃり、この和訳で良いということであれば、回答なりコメントなり頂けませんでしょうか？　その場合は和訳を残したまま回答受付を再開することができます :)

Comment: 元質問のユーザが恐らく別IDで質問し直してしまっています。英語質問の方がクローズ状態なので重複投票もできません(ポジティブ回答が無いため) - https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/47189/3060

Comment: @cubick さん、なるほど、情報提供ありがとうございます。こうなると元の質問者さんと同一かどうかに関わらず重複なので、対処としては、ここで同意をとった後英語版の方はモデレーター権限で再オープン→重複クローズするのが良さそうですね。適宜質問者さんにフォローを入れるのも必須です。

Comment: 重複にするには1点だけ不安があって、まだ日本語質問の方の回答に vote が集まっていないんですよね。

Comment: 当該の質問が自動削除されてしまいました。重複先の質問があるので、今回はそちらを参照頂くということになりそうです。

Answer (score 3):

スタックオーバーフローでは質問したら終わりではなく、閲覧者・回答者からのコメントに応対し、よい回答にはプラス投票し、１つの回答を承認するまでが質問者の責務との認識です。

今回、匿名IPユーザーから和訳編集の提案には単なる翻訳ではなく追加情報が含まれており、元質問者であろうことが推測は出来ましたが、質問者の責務を果たせない（特に回答を承認できない）のであれば編集の却下・ロールバックされてしかるべき、と私は考えます。