# クローズ理由に、英語の質問はオフトピックであるという選択肢を追加してほしい

Tags: 討議, 完了, 話題の範囲, 質問のクローズ

最近、英語での質問をそこそこの頻度で見かけます。

[英語による質問への対処法](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2181/754) や [英語の投稿を訳してしまっても良い？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2309/754) で議論された結果は、英語の質問は基本的にクローズしていく、何かしらの事情で望まれている場合には日本語に翻訳してもいい、であると思っています。

そしてそういった事情を知らない人のために、現在、 [Can I ask questions in English? / 英語で質問してもいいですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314/754) のまとめが作成されている状態だと認識しています。

---

毎回英語の質問を見かけるたびに、事情を説明する文章を記述し、上のまとめ Wiki のリンクを探して併記した上で、クローズ表を投票するには、割と手間です。「英語での質問は翻訳 or 本家 or 事情を説明してください」 がクローズ理由であるような、オフトピック票を、クローズ票の選択肢として用意することはできないでしょうか。

---

現状の結論っぽいものを承認していくことにします。議論が発生して、総意っぽいものが変われば、随時変更します。自分の承認の変更が追‌​いついていないと思われる場合には、コメン‌​トなどで知らせてください。

Comment: カスタムなクローズ理由を最大３つまで作れます。これがいいアイデアだと思います。もし作れるなら、どの文書を使うかを決めましょう。

Comment: 投票数はmjyさんの案が一番多いです。とりあえず承認してもいいかなと思っています。

Comment: @sun-solar-arrow Ack.

Comment: @unarist (このコメントは通知されるのか。。？) 承認を更新しました。

Comment: 意見も落ち着いてきてmjyさんの回答が良さげですが、どこまでの期間でカスタムクローズに決定するのでしょうか？、投票を何時までと決めるか、もう反論がなさそうなので決めてしまえばいいような気がしています。

Comment: @Myaku こういうときのためのモデレーターだと思っています。個人的には、同じく、収束したと思っているので、この承認されたものを採用すれば良いと思います。

Comment: ＠は編集した人かコメントした人にしか通知されないのです。/ すぐ設定できるだろうと思って特に知らせずにいたのですが、既にモデレーター陣で調整を進めています。反映までもう少しお待ちください。

Comment: mjyさんの案を採用し、カスタムクローズ理由として登録しました。クローズ→オフトピックから選択できるかと思います。

Comment: @unarist オフトピックの理由から、「ヘルプセンターで定義されている…」の説明が、なくなってしまってさいるように見受けられています。。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

他の方の案に反対というわけでもないですし、長々と議論することでもないと思うので、早めにモデレータの方が決めてしまうのがよいと思いますが、一応私案を。

> 当サイト ([**ja**.stackoverflow.com](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)) は Stack Overflow ([stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/)) とは独立して日本語の質問を扱うサイトとして運営されています。詳しくは、[Can I ask questions in English? / 英語で質問してもいいですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314/3054) をご覧ください。
>   この質問を日本語に編集していただければ、引き続きこのサイトで扱うことが出来ます。
>   英語で質問をするには、[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) へ新しく質問を投稿する必要があります。

以下の点を踏まえ作成しました。

- 誤解を解く
  まず ja.stackoverflow.com は Stack Overflow とは別サイトだと伝える必要があります。Stack Overflow のインターフェイスがローカライズされた物だと思われているのです。
- 「日本語版」という言葉を使わない
  現時点では、このサイトのどこにも「日本語版」と書かれていません。
- 指示でなしに、次に何をやればよいかを伝える
  ユーザーがサービスの利用方法を間違えるのは、運営が悪いのです。本来はまず謝罪から入るべきです。当サイトの性質上、そこまでは必要ないと思いますが、ユーザーが命令されたと感じないように表現する必要があります。
- 日本語を中心にする
  英語しか読めない人は英語を拾い読みしますから、[Can I ask questions in English? / 英語で質問してもいいですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314/3054) へのリンクへ誘導され、それで十分です。
  そもそも、当サイトに英語で質問してしまうのは、ほとんど全て、英語より日本語が得意な人です。私の予想だと、むしろ英語は不得意な人が多いはずです。

Comment: モデレーターが決めてしまうに +1.

Comment: [試しにはめ込み合成](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa8yk.png)。長いかと思いましたが、別に悪くないですね。

Comment: いろいろと考えてみた結果、コミュニティとして一番大事なのはアイデンティティである、今のこのサイトのアイデンティティは「日本語‌​でのプログラミングに関する技術的 Q & Aの収集・蓄積である」、そこから逆算して考えると。。この案がいいのでは、と今現在の私は思っています。

Comment: 良いと思います。日本語を取り扱うサイトであるので日本語の対応文であったほうが"日本語で書き込むべきだ"と伝わるので個人的には、この案が好きです。

Answer (score 4):

私が考えた案は

> English Questions are off-topic for [Stack Overflow in Japanese](http://ja.stackoverflow.com). We recommend use [Stack Overflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com). For more information:[Can I ask question in English?](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314/). 
>   英語の質問は[日本語版Stack Overflow](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)では[トピック](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)から外れています。もしも英語で質問したいなら[英語版](http://stackoverflow.com)をご利用ください。詳しくは[英語で質問していいですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314/)をご覧ください。

英語版SOのクローズ票を参考にしました。しかし、

- FAQに丸投げもどうか？
- 対処の方法を書いた方がいいかもしれない
- オフトピック…では無いよね？

Comment: 投票する人や、傍で見ている人の事も考えると、このように日本語も併記されているのが良いと思います。情報量が少なくなるのが難点ではありますが、FAQへの誘導で補えているのではないでしょうか。（「皆、これくらいの英語は解るだろう」としてしまうと、「じゃあこの質問の英語も解るでしょう」となり、なんでオフトピックなんだっけ、という話になり、このサイトのアイデンティティがやばい）

Comment: 良いのではないでしょうか？割と日本語話者であろう方が英語で投稿されているパターンも多いので……。正直プロフィールが日本語の人とかMETAとか他の質問を見てないのかな？とか思っちゃいます

Comment: 日本語もほしい理由としては「１．”これ機械翻訳だよね？"と思う投稿があるので、そういった人が英語を一目見て分かるのか？(英文を機械翻訳に投げそう…)」と言うのと、「２．クローズされた理由が質問者だけでなく質問を見た他のユーザが一目で分かるようにする」という理由からです。

Comment: SEネットワークにあまり慣れていない人が読む可能性が高いことを考えると、「オフトピック」という言葉を使わずに説明できるとわかりやすいかもしれません。多分こんな感じに表示されます： https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfVFa.png

Comment: @unarist それを考慮すると… "トピックから外れています"がわかりやすい気がします。

Comment: 私はまさに「オフトピック」という言葉をこれまで使う機会がなかったので、ここで見かけた時は思わず検索しに行きました。ですので、別の言葉で説明されるとありがたく思います。

Comment: 1) 何語であるかは、厳密にはトピック（質問内容）ではない気もするので、その点からも「オフトピック」を使わない方向に賛成です。（カスタムの"オフトピック"クローズ理由として追加するわけではありますが。）「英語で質問したいなら...」は対処方法でもあるので、この線に一票です。 2) 英語で書いてきている人に向けてのメッセージなので、英語と日本語の順番を入れ替えるのはどうでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

FAQでも使った文章を流用して、例えばこんな感じでしょうか。

> We are **Stack Overflow for Japanese speakers**, so questions here should be in Japanese. We recommend asking on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) instead. If you really want to ask on here, see [our FAQ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314) in Meta.

気になっている点：

- FAQに日本語での説明もあることがわかるほうがよい？
- 日本語で書き直してほしい、といった内容を含めるべき？

Comment: とても良いと思います。ですが、クローズ票を投じる(もしくは質問を通報する)人が英語が分からない人だと少し投票しづらい気がします。

Answer (score 0):

sun-solar-arrowさんの案でいい気もしますが、もう一つ方向性が浮かんだので書いてみます。

> ここは日本語版 Stack Overflow ですから、質問は日本語で書いてください。詳しくは [英語で質問してもいいですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314) をご覧ください。 English questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow in Japanese. You may get help on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). See also: [Can I ask question in English?](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314).

日本語の文章ではオフトピックだとか英語版だとかよりも、日本語で書いてほしいという点をアピールするようにしました。併せて英語の文章にも本家へのリンクを入れました。
<sub>（というか本家のカスタムクローズ理由ほぼそのままです。unless they have a specific reason を入れようか迷いましたが）</sub>

日本語版トップへのリンクは特になくてもいいかな？と思ったので削ってあります。

Comment: 「〜ですから、〜してください」というのは、ユーザー同士で教え合うという文脈では、よいと思います。しかし、ユーザの投票によるものとはいえ、システム（運営側）からのメッセージと捉えると、少しフォーマルさに欠けると思います。細かい話で恐縮ですが、受け取り方によっては、若干のトゲを感じてしまう人もいるかもしれません。間違いを指摘されている状況ですから、「『〜ですから』と言われても、決めたのはそちらでしょ？ 知らないよ、そんなの」となりかねないです。

Comment: やはり、sun-solar-arrow さんの回答のように端的に事実を伝える形がよいのではないでしょうか。「オフトピック」という言葉を避けるなら、「対象外になっています」あるいは「扱われていません」に置き換えるなどでいかがでしょうか。

Comment: @mjy このような口調に逆に違和感があるというのは私も気になっていた点で、おっしゃる通りだと思います。オフトピックも別にあえて避ける必要もないかなと思い始めてます。