# 日本語必須化時のエラーメッセージ

Tags: 討議, 英語

質問投稿時に日本語が含まれていない場合に表示するエラーメッセージを募集します。

現在、このサイトでは日本語の質問のみ受け付けています。質問者が本文に日本語を含めていない際は「提案」として下記のメッセージが表示されます。

> If you would like to post in English, please read [this FAQ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2314/) first. ／ 英語で投稿したい場合、先に[こちらのFAQ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2314/)をご覧ください。

私は、これを「提案」ではなく対処が必須のブロック処理とすることを要望する予定です。（先日のモデレーター選挙への[立候補時](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/election/2?tab=nomination#post-95030)には自動クローズを行なうbotを実装したいと表明しましたが、既にこれが可能な仕組みが有ることが解りましたので方針を変更しました）

これは以前より日本語版コミュニティーから要望されており、大きな支持がある一方で反対意見は一つも出ていません。要望をこのメタサイトに投稿した後は速やかにStack Exchange社へエスカレーション可能だと予想します。そのため、作業に必要な詳細をあらかじめ用意して提示することが重要です。

つきましては、質問者に解り易いブロック時のエラーメッセージを策定したいです。現在の提案メッセージですと、完全にブロックされるようになった際には不十分かも知れないと感じています。皆様の案やご意見などありましたら、よろしくお願い致します。

---

参考:

- [Can I ask questions in English? / 英語で質問してもいいですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2314/)
- [英語で投稿されようとしている質問を、未然に誘導する仕組みが欲しい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2838/)
- [英語質問のシステム的ブロック](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2523/)
- [クローズ理由に、英語の質問はオフトピックであるという選択肢を追加してほしい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2323/)

提案メッセージが表示されている様子（右側に出ていますが、このまま投稿が可能です。特に他のエラーが出ている場合は見逃されていそうです）:

> [image: スクリーンショット]

ブロックメッセージが表示されている様子（内容が空の場合の例）:

> [image: スクリーンショット]

[他サイト](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)でブロックメッセージが表示されている様子（このようにリンクも挿入できます）:

> [image: スクリーンショット]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

入力時のバリデーションチェックなので、端的にお断りする短い文言が良いと思います。
下記のメッセージはいかがでしょうか。

```
Questions must be written in Japanese.／本文は日本語が必須です。 See [this FAQ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314).
```

Comment: 邦語は意味がふたつあって日本語を意味しないことがあるのと、日本語初学者には分かりづらい言葉なので、「日本語」で良さそうです。

Comment: ご指摘いただいた通り、Rev.1で「邦語」という言い回しを使っていましたが変更しました。

Comment: このメッセージで要望を[投稿しました](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3907/3054)。
回答の投稿時にも適用されるかも知れないことを説明し忘れていましたが、この文面ですとどちらでも問題なさそうですので、よかったです。