# ブロックリストにある非日本語投稿へのアクションをブロックに変更して下さい

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了, 英語, ブロックリスト

現在、本文に日本語を含まない投稿には警告が出されています。これを警告でなくブロックに変更して下さい。可能ならば、このブロックは質問の投稿のみに適用し、回答には適用しないで下さい。しかし、それが無理ならば質問と回答、両方の投稿でブロックするので構いません。

現在の警告処理はこのサイト（日本語版）のブロックリスト(blocklist)に含まれています。この設定を変更することでブロックが可能になると考えています。

#### 現在の設定値

- **id**: 19
- **Type**: Post Body
- **Pattrn**: `^(?![ぁ-ん])([^ぁ-ん]+)$`
- **Match Action**: Warning
- **Message**: `If you would like to post in English, please read <a href="https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314" target="_blank">this FAQ</a> first. ／ 英語で投稿したい場合、先に<a href="https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314" target="_blank">こちらのFAQ</a>をご覧ください。`

#### 変更後の設定値

- **Pattern**: `^[^あ-ン一-鿯]+$` (or `^[^\u3042-\u30f3\u4e00-\u9fef]+$` to use Unicode escapes)
- **Match Action**: Block
- **Message**: `本文は日本語が必須です。<a href="https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314" target="_blank">こちらのFAQ</a>をご覧ください。 ／ Posts must be written in Japanese. See <a href="https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314" target="_blank">this FAQ</a>.`

実装イメージ:

> [image: Screenshot]

---

#### ブロックに変更する理由

現在、Stack Overflow本家（英語版）とこのサイト（日本語版）の関係は広く理解されていません。そのため、間違えてこのサイトに英語で質問を寄せる方が多くみられます。そういった質問は全てクローズされています。

クローズされた質問者は、自分の間違いに気付いて適切な対応を行う必要が有ります。この状況は新規参加者に対して親切とは言えず、参加の障壁となっています。実際に、最初にこの間違いをした質問者の一部はStack Overflow本家にも、日本語版にも、二度と現われません。

間違いのチェックは可能な限り便利でストレスの少ないものであるべきです。具体的には、

- 間違いに気付くのは早い方が良い
- 人よりもマシンに指摘される方が良い
- やり直す作業は少ない方が良い

と言えるでしょう。これを実現するには、自動的なチェックにより入力画面から即座に反応を得られるブロック処理が適切と考えます。現在の警告インターフェースでは不十分であることが実証されています。

#### パターンを変更する理由

ブロックに変更する都合上、日本語の判定は寛容にしました。回答も対象となる可能性にも配慮しました。

#### メッセージを変更する理由

ブロックに変更する都合上、表現を調整する必要が有りました。このメッセージは[メタサイトで募集](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3905/)しました。

---

#### 予想されるデメリット

- コードのみの回答が不可になるかも知れない:
  現在はコードのみの回答がまれに有りますが、回答にもブロック設定が適用されることになると、これが新たにはできなくなります。FAQの文面も調整が必要になるでしょう。
- 意図的に英語でなされる質問も不可になる:
  日本語に関する質問をこのサイト(日本語版)で100%英語で行ないたい、といった需要には応えられなくなります。

#### 過去の要望との関係

過去にも動機は異なりますが、[同趣旨の要望](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2523)がありました。ただし、今回の要望では、回答を同じ条件でブロックすることになっても構わない、としています。使用する機能も既存のものを具体的に提案しています。これならば、却下される可能性は殆ど無いと思います。失望される方もいらっしゃると思いますが、過去の要望にあった通り、英語質問に英語で回答が付くなどの事態もあった事を考えれば、このデメリットは許容して先に進むのが良いと考えます。

ここ数年、英語質問はモデレーター（特に cubick さん）による迅速なクローズに依存して対処されており、大きな問題を感じない方も多いかも知れません。しかし、このような貢献を当たり前に考えるべきではありません。このような負担は、モデレーターへの立候補者が現れない原因にもなり得ます。

また、明かに簡単に実装できそうな要望が却下されるという経験は、コミュニティーの自治への参加意欲を削ぎます。よって、過去の要望を妥協を含めながらも通り易い形で再提出することには意義があると考えます。

---

皆様には、過去の要望と違う点（回答にも日本語が必須になる可能性が高い）にも留意いただき、ご意見や投票をお願いいたします。

Comment: エラーメッセージを更新しました。明後日（9月9日）頃にエスカレーションする予定ですが、議論の点が残っていれば急がずに時間を取りますので、ご意見は引き続きお待ちしております。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

変更が完了しました。もし何か問題がある場合には、どうぞお知らせください！

Comment: So far, I don't see any problems.
I think this has significantly reduced the moderation costs for this site.
thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

ご提案ありがとうございます。
全面的に趣旨へ賛同いたします。

> コードのみの回答が不可になるかも知れない

以下の理由からルール化して良いと思います。
コードのみの回答ではコード全体を読んで理解したり、質問のコードとの差分を目視で追わないといけない例が多いです。
回答には文頭またはコードコメントに要旨や重要箇所を入れることを許容していただくことで、分かりにくい回答が減る効果も期待できます。
コードだけ貼って分かれば十分という意見もありますが、日本語を一言付与しても日本語話者の労力はそれほど多くかからないはずです。

> 意図的に英語でなされる質問も不可になる

問題ないと思います。
どうしてもSOjaで英語質問したい場合はその理由を日本語で行頭に記載していただきたいです。
そうでないと本文を読まず機械的にクローズ票を投じるユーザが出てくると予想されます。

重箱の隅ですが、「Questions must be...」が回答に適用されると英語部分がマッチしないかもしれません。
私の案は確認なく自由に改変していただいて構いませんので、Questions→Postsなど適した表現があればご修正をお願いいたします。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。Posts にしました。

Answer (score 3):

英語で投稿する人は (体感で) 九割がた日本語話者かと思うので、エラーメッセージも「日本語 / 英語」の順に表示した方が良いかなと思います。